# PHP Limit words breaks div in string

Tags: php, html, string-length

I use the following php function to limit word length:

```
function limit_words($phrase, $max_words) {
   $phrase_array = explode(' ',$phrase);

   if(count($phrase_array) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
      $phrase = implode(' ',array_slice($phrase_array, 0, $max_words)).'...';

   return $phrase;
}
```

No say I have a string that contains a div or span class e.g.

```
$string = 'I went to the shop to buy a <span class="highlight"> lollipop </span>';

echo limit_words($string,10);
```

results in:

```
I went to the shop to buy a <span class="highlight"> lollipop
```

and it's missing the last div closer `</span>`

This some times results in messing up my content futher down, is there away to ensure it doesnt cut of the closer tag before it limits the string?

Many thanks

Comment: it wont let me edit the post - it was ment to say last div closer "</span>" instead of last div closer ""

Comment: If you don't need HTML tags in the final result, you can always use `strip_tags` before your function - https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: @memaxt the [edit] button is right there at the end of your post, under the little blue tags. If you need to put HTML code in an otherwise text sentence, use backticks. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @ADyson when i submit the edit its says an error occurred....stackoverflow tech issue by the looks of it..will keep trying

Comment: I changed it for you. It's a bit unclear what issue you were having. Hope that reflects what you wanted to show

Comment: P.S. Your example doesn't do what you said it does - demo: https://3v4l.org/4gPCp . The closing `</span>` is still there in the output. Please ensure you provide us a [mre]  of the issue, otherwise will be difficult to help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, question is now set perfectly thanks for updating it, my edit function now works also. But my original issue still remains as it will cut of the 11th word (which may be the end of a div tag)